# "Entity is not api accessible" when using the Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

I'm attempting to use the Metadata API to add a custom button to my contact layout:

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/

I'm following the example written here:
https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/24/apex-metadata-api-and-spring14-keys-to-the-kingdom/

To begin, I copied the MetadataService.cls and MetadataServiceTest.cls into my force.com developer instance. Then, I attempted to run through the example by first creating a webLink MetadataService, however when I get to the last line it gets stuck:

```
MetadataService.WebLink webLink = new MetadataService.WebLink();
webLink.fullName = 'Test__c.googleButton';
webLink.availability = 'online';
webLink.displayType = 'button';
webLink.encodingKey = 'UTF-8';
webLink.hasMenubar = false;
webLink.hasScrollbars = true;
webLink.hasToolbar = false;
webLink.height = 600;
webLink.isResizable = true;
webLink.linkType = 'url';
webLink.masterLabel = 'google';
webLink.openType = 'newWindow';
webLink.position = 'none';
webLink.protected_x = false;
webLink.showsLocation = false;
webLink.showsStatus = false;
webLink.url = 'http://www.google.com';
webLink.width = 600;
service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { webLink })[0];
```

I am getting the error "Entity is not api accessible". This is my first time using the Metadata API and I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use the install link and then try again.

Comment: Also if you include the entire script you're trying to run, that would be helpful. Please **[edit]** your post with any new updates.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Updated with full code (sorry should have done that initially)- also, what install link?

Comment: There's a big, shiny `Deploy to Salesforce` button on the github page that leads to [this page](https://githubsfdeploy.herokuapp.com/?owner=financialforcedev&repo=apex-mdapi).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. In the meantime, do you happen to know if the full code deploy is necessary for just what I'm trying to do above? It seems like it will bulk up the package by quite a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it still seems like an incomplete snippet. What's `service`?

Comment: Good question. I tried to full deploy and I'm still getting the same error. I had thought 'service' might be a native apex keyword. If it helps, I'm trying to follow the first example on this page: https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/24/apex-metadata-api-and-spring14-keys-to-the-kingdom/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44120/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-user1813867).

Comment: I'll see if you're available a bit later today - I have to run out the door

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you haven't instantiated `service` to anything. You could reproduce the error with this simple snippet as your entire execution:

```
service.doSomething();
```

You need to create a new `MetadataPort` to call the `createMetadata` method.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
List<MetadataService.Metadata> elements = List<MetadataService.Metadata> { webLink };
MetadataService.SaveResult result = service.createMetadata(elements)[0];
```

I found this class by simply searching the [MetadatService](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) class for `createMetadata(`.

Comment: N.B. `Service` is considered by SFDC as some internal SObject and hence the error `Entity is not api accessible`

Comment: Same phenomenon can be observed with `Project` and some others.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! However now I'm getting a remote site error "System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://na30.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/37.0" Shouldn't that url/domain be included by default since it's my own domain?

Comment: @user Nope you still have to add remote site settings. https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/07/29/post-install-apex-metadata-api-configuration-solved/